# Validation with spring 3 for equally null value not working

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a check box called *payment mode*.

```
[form:checkbox path="cashPayment" id="cash" value="Cash"
form:checkbox path="chequePayment" id="cheque" value="Cheque" ]
```

When I click on the cash checkbox it will show a cash textbox with zero value initially.
My condition is to check that if the cash is zero, it should not pass.

Answer (score 0):

It should not pass means you want to provide a validation and stop saving the record in the database/ Is that what you mean by "should not pass"?

You can try using jQuery validation for this. You can also use spring validation during your post method in the controller.

You can check in the validator like if the value of Cash is true then check the value of cash textbox, if the cash text is 0 then you can use rejectValue() method in spring validtor to reject the value. 
A good example is avaialble in this website
http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html